# laravel resource controller store method not working for some users

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I m using laravel 8 auth middleware on a group route and under that group route there are multiple resource routes.
**Store method is not working for some users.**
I have checked all possibility like csrf and trailing slash etc.
its posting data to index method for some users but for other users its working fine.
**web.php**

```
 Route::name('')->middleware(['auth','CheckRole'])->group(function () {
    //role routes
    Route::resource('role', RoleController::class);
    //role dumpsites
    Route::resource('dumpsite', DumpsiteController::class);
});
```

**controller --it large i cant add whole**

```
public function store(Request $request){
   $o = new Dumpsite;
   $o->remarks = $request->post('remarks');
   $o->save();
   return redirect()->route('dumpsite.edit', ['dumpsite' => $o->id])->with('success', 'Submitted successfully');
}
```

**view**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="{{route('dumpsite.store')}}" method="POST">
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be helpful to include related code, so your `route`, `controller` and probably `form`.

Comment: The action can be prohibited by a policy or intermediary

Comment: @Unflux please check i have added code

Comment: You have used auth and CheckRole middleware for you resource controller, make sure middlewares are passing successfully.

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh.....other time its working well but for some users its not working i have dd route name in CheckRole middleware so its showing dumpsite.index when posting data. so its not going to store route sometimes

Comment: It's not clear from your answer it the middleware if passing or not. Points to check: Cache in users navigators (very usual), cookies (idem), headers (navigator language and user agent). Does the same user, in other PC, work?

Comment: well it can't POST to 'index' because it is a GET route, if it was using POST it would be using the store method, so something is redirecting or the wrong http method is being used for some reason

Comment: @Sourcerer its not working on any other pc but it works on localhost and another server
but not working on current server

Comment: If the same user (e.g. John) is working in developer server (localhost), and in other servers, and from PCs, obviously the problems is with the server and not with the code. Check configuration parameters (.env) in deep, and the connection with your authorization server (Active Directory? OAuth?)